# Detect when a beacon changes color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map where you have to "capture" all the beacons by changing their color. Is there any way (in single player vanilla Minecraft) to detect when a beacon color is changed? I was thinking of maybe using observers, but those would only detect if any block was placed there.

Comment: Maybe try _/testfor_ for the different colored glass above the beacon. I think there isn't a way to detect a color of a beacon, as it may also have multiple colors (white until the colored glass, just then becoming colored, etc.)

Comment: I thought /testfor was for entitys, isn't it?

Comment: Is the map set up so that there's only one place to put a stained glass block, or could it be in any of the ~250 blocks above the beacon?

Comment: well I made the glass blocks with the CanPlace tag for ONLY beacons, so It shouldn't be possible to place them anywhere else. (unless they cheat)          (also sorry I'm so late It only showed that comment when I clicked a tiny button XD)

Comment: @Aperson Yeah, _/testfor_ is only for entities, but, as minecraftprank's answer says, you can use _/testforblock_. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

`~~~/testforblock`(s)
You may use this when using `/execute`

Summon an invisible `Armor_Stand` (with the name 'Beacon') inside the beacon and then do a sort of '`/execute @e[type=Armor_Stand,name=Beacon] ~ ~ ~ /testforblocks XXX`' to test if a block changed

Comment: wait should I replace XXX with ~ ~1 ~ for the block above the stands? (I put them inside the beacons)

Comment: ok so I did that but it still says: failed to execute /testforblocks ~ ~1 ~ as Beacon :(

Comment: there are TWO sets of coords that you have to enter! not just one!

Comment: ugh! it still says failed to execute!

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys I finally found the command. it goes as follows:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:stained_glass 0
```

but there is another problem. now I need to know (please don't call me a noob but) how to add 1 to a players score I simply can't figure it out. Help? (again)
btw this is what will go in place of (command).

Comment: If you have another question, it may be more appropriate to ask it as a separate question, and select an answer which you think sufficiently answered your original question. You can always link back to this question in the new question if its an extension of this question

Comment: well it kind of is an extension because its the same command, just that I now need help finishing it off.

Comment: If you're modifying your question then you should change it in the question above or ask a new question entirely, not ask a new question in an answer

Comment: Ok your right I'm gonna make a new question

Comment: Great! If any of the answers here helped you figure out the command then you should also accept it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer

Comment: _Ok guys **I** finally found the command. it goes as follows:_ Like really, _**You**_? I mean, this is totally based on **MY** comment below the question and **minecraftprank's** answer. I think _you_ would not find out the answer if you didn't read my comment, that actually advises you to check the stained glass above, and not the beacon color. This is also the same thing as minecraftprank answered...